# How to restrict the import of a Module in F# to a local scope?

Tags: f#, namespaces, module, scope

Is it possible to locally restrict the import of a module, preferrably combining this with `Module Abbreviations`? The goal is to avoid polluting my current module with symbols from imports.

e.g. (inspired by OCaml) something like that:

```
let numOfEvenIntegersSquaredGreaterThan n =
    let module A = Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.Array in
        [|1..100|] |> A.filter (fun x -> x % 2 = 0)
                   |> A.map    (fun x -> x * x)
                   |> A.filter (fun x -> x > n)
                   |> A.length

let elementsGreaterThan n =
    let module A = Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.List in
        [1..100] |> A.filter (fun x -> x > n)
```

Additionally is there a way to achieve something similar with namespaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The goal is to avoid polluting my
>   current module with symbols from
>   imports.

Note that `open Array` is not allowed in F# (contrary to OCaml).
You can use abbreviations on modules, but only in the global scope:

```
module A = Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.Array
```

Instead of Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.Array, you can use Array. So your code would be:

```
let numOfEvenIntegersSquaredGreaterThan n =
    [|1..100|] |> Array.filter (fun x -> x % 2 = 0)
               |> Array.map    (fun x -> x * x)
               |> Array.filter (fun x -> x > n)
               |> Array.length
```

If you want to reuse the same code for Arrays and Lists, you might want to use the `Seq` module:

```
let elementsGreaterThan n =
    [1..100] |> Seq.filter (fun x -> x > n)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Laurent. Using Array was just an arbitrary - and in retrospect unlucky - example though. My goal is to open an arbitrary Module (or namespace) _only_ within a limited scope like within a single 'let binding'. If I understand you correctly this is (currently?) not possible in F#?

Comment: Indeed. I hope it will be possible in the future. In the meantime, I think adding a few abbreviations in the global scope doesn't pollute much (but try to avoid 1-char names).